# UnicodeEncodeError on reading tags from html data

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to read a html file on my disk. I am using BeautifulSoup to work with the tags in it. My file can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8PzLGTuH2rjSkJCd0o1SG0wS28/view?usp=sharing) . I am getting this unicode error when trying to print the `<p>` tags. I am not even able to store the `<p>` tags in another file. :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\HTMLdownload\HTMLdownload\src\Extract images and caption.py", line 61, in <module>
    print(img_data)
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\HTMLdownload\HTMLdownload\src\Extract images and caption.py", line 57, in <module>
    print(cap_data)
  File "c:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2212' in position 330: character maps to <undefined>
```

Here is my code:

```
loc # some location on disk
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(loc,'r'),"html.parser")
fig_data= soup.select("dl.figure")
for i in fig_data:
    img_data=i.select("img.figure")
    print(img_data)
    cap_data=i.select(".caption p")
    print(cap_data)
```

In this code, I am trying to get the image tags and their respective captions. From these image tags I will be taking the links of the images out.

To solve, I have already tried to encode to utf-8 or other options like repr(cap_data)  , but still I am getting this error using Python 3.

Problematic text is this:

```
<p id="">Weight change of <em>A. caliginosa</em> in pots containing Springmount soil kept at 15<sup>&deg;</sup>C (&plusmn;1&deg;C) for 10 weeks. Vertical bars represent standard errors of the means, <em>n</em>=10. Bars with same letters are not significantly different at the 5% level. C6=<em>A. caliginosa</em> at a density of 6 worms pot<sup>&minus;1</sup>. C12=<em>A. caliginosa</em> at a density of 12 worms pot<sup>&minus;1</sup>. CL=<em>A. caliginosa</em> and <em>A. longa</em> at a density of 6 worms pot<sup>&minus;1</sup> each.</p>
```

Comment: The data outside your program is encoded. Therefore, before passing it to Beautiful Soup you should _decode_ it.

Comment: @holdenweb  I am getting error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'  when I am trying to decode the content from file directly

Comment: Sorry: a closer look at the traceback indicates the issue is more likely an input character that can't be represented in the Windows encoding used by your terminal. Have you tried writing the output to a file, with UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: @holdenweb Yes, I am able to write to a file with UTF-8 encoding. Actually I am not able to understand the problem here, because if I open that html file without beautiful soup I can see the whole content on console. But when I am parsing it with bs and then trying to print the p tags, it shows error.  For debugging the program, I would need to see the content on the console. I have included the problematic text from the html file.

Comment: The problem is the Unicode MINUS SIGN, probably generated when BSoup parses the `&minus;` enitity in your input string. It seems it's turning into a valid Unicode character during the creation of the soup, and not converting it back into an HTML entity before delivering it to you. So the text you are parsing is indeed ASCII, but it contains an entity whose representation your terminal cannot handle.

Comment: Investigate either `soup.p.prettify` (which turns non-representable characters into numeric character entities) or the `EntitySubstitution` class, which allows you to control the production of HTML rather more closely.

Answer (score 0):

As the traceback shows, you should `repr(img_data)`. See also the [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unicodeencodeerror+charmap+undefined) on the topic. Alas, there is not a single canonical target (so far).

Comment: I have tried but still  no help.. It am still not able to print the cap_data. img_data I am able to print

Comment: so obviously you need to `print(repr(cap_data))`

Comment: sorry for my mistake in the question,  but I have already tried that